# VGA on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerpoint, projector

I have my Windows 10 laptop hooked up to a projector via VGA. It was working fine, except today (2 days before our group's performance in which I'm running a PowerPoint presentation). When I unplugged the VGA plug to kill the video portion, but left the audio plugged in, everything stopped; the presentation stopped in it's tracks. Obviously I wanted to stop video, but allow audio to continue.

Nothing was changed, no updates were run lately, nothing done. Anyone have a thought why this stopped?

Comment: What audio source and output were you using? Does your laptop have more than one graphics card or audio source? Check this under properties on the sound icon in the task bar.

Comment: VGA has nothing to do with the audio stopping VGA only can carry a video signal

Comment: If you press (Windows Key + P) and choose `PC Screen Only`, will it does what you want instead of plugging out the cable?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that because PowerPoint automatically switches to Presenter View when you are plugged into an external display, unplugging the video made the PowerPoint presentation exit into editing mode. It is normal behaviour.

Comment: That's probably it;  so as a test, before starting the show, choose Slide Show tab and remove the checkmark next to "Use Presenter View" then try it again.